# How to animate view and meanwhile preserve view in its original location during the animation

Tags: android, view, android-animation

I want to implement an animation similar to the animation when an app is opened in Mac OS (view scales, gets bigger and at the same time, it gets transparent, while it is already in its original place too. In the attached picture you can see the animation on calculator app)

[image]

How can I do that? I'm trying to use this animation on ActionBar home button if it helps.
thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Bitmap of your View, do some transformations on your Bitmap and then animate it instead of the View.
This pattern is often used when dragging views around.

There is on episode of the DevBytes series which explains this pretty good.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BZIvjMgH-Q